# Select Rows based on Entire Subset matching a condition,

Tags: sql, subquery, conditional-statements, aggregate, subset

I have a series of reports that I'd like to display as available for download - based on the source information being uploaded to the system.  Each report may exist for multiple reporting periods and may require one or multiple source files to be uploaded before being available.

My tables look like this:

- Report - stores the report type (ReportID) and Description
- ReportDependency - stores the report type (ReportID) and the
  dependencies to generate that report (may be one or multiple) (SourceTypeID)
- SourceType - stores the different types of source files that might be uploaded to the system.
- Source - stores the source data files that have been uploaded (SourceTypeID, ReportingPeriodID, and UploadDateTime)
- Reporting Period - stores the various reporting periods.

[image: TablesChart]

Based on the sources available (uploaded to the system), I want to show what reports can be generated/downloaded.

I have come up with this, but it's not correct:

```
SELECT
RD.ReportID, RP.ReportingPeriodID, COUNT(S.UploadDateTime) AS    
     DependenciesUploaded
FROM
ReportDependency RD
    INNER JOIN
Source S ON RD.SourceTypeID = S.SourceTypeID
    INNER JOIN
ReportingPeriod RP ON S.ReportingPeriodID = RP.ReportingPeriodID
GROUP BY
     RP.ReportingPeriodID, RD.ReportID
HAVING
    COUNT(S.UploadDateTime) = (SELECT COUNT(SourceTypeID) FROM ReportDependency WHERE ReportID = RD.ReportID)
```

If my data looks like this:

[image]

I should get:

- Report 1 for ReportingPeriod 1 is available
- Report 2 not available yet
- Report 3 for ReportingPeriod 2 is available

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Russell

Comment: "`I have come up with this, but it's not correct:`" Do you get an error, or is it just not returning the data you are expecting?

Comment: Not the result I was expecting.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

When you do your first inner join, should it be

```
ReportDependency RD
  INNER JOIN
Source S ON RD.SourceTypeID = S.SourceTypeID
```

instead of

```
Source S ON RD.SourceTypeID = S.SourceID
```

so that you are not comparing `ID` to `TYPEID`.

Comment: That didn't solve the query at all, just corrected a typo.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

I have continued to work on this...  In case it helps someone, here's a solution that seems to be working (not done testing yet).  (I may have tweaked a table or two, I can't remember; hopefully this is enough to help someone else.)

Russell

```
            SELECT
                *
            FROM
                (
                    SELECT DISTINCT
                        R.ReportID,
                        R.FilePathAndName,
                        RP.ReportingPeriodID,
                        COUNT(RD.SourceTypeID) OVER (PARTITION BY R.ReportID, R.FilePathAndName, RP.ReportingPeriodID) AS SourcesNeeded
                    FROM
                        luReportingPeriod RP
                            CROSS JOIN
                        Report R
                            INNER JOIN
                        ReportDependency RD ON R.ReportTypeID = RD.ReportTypeID
                            INNER JOIN
                        (
                        SELECT 
                        S.ReportingPeriodID,
                        S.SourceTypeID
                            FROM
                        luReportingPeriod RP
                            INNER JOIN
                        Source S ON (RP.ReportingPeriodID = S.ReportingPeriodID)
                            GROUP BY
                                S.ReportingPeriodID,
                                S.SourceTypeID
                        ) AS AvailableSources ON RP.ReportingPeriodID = AvailableSources.ReportingPeriodID AND RD.SourceTypeID = AvailableSources.SourceTypeID
                    GROUP BY
                        R.ReportID,
                        R.FilePathAndName,
                        RP.ReportingPeriodID,
                        RD.SourceTypeID
                ) AS Data
                INNER JOIN
                (
                    SELECT ReportTypeID, COUNT(SourceTypeID) AS SourcesNeeded
                    FROM
                        ReportDependency
                    GROUP BY ReportTypeID
                ) AS RequirementCount
                ON RequirementCount.ReportTypeID = Data.ReportID AND RequirementCount.SourcesNeeded = Data.SourcesNeeded
                INNER JOIN
                    luReportingPeriod ON Data.ReportingPeriodID = luReportingPeriod.ReportingPeriodID
                ORDER BY luReportingPeriod.Year DESC, luReportingPeriod.Month DESC, Data.FilePathAndName
```